# Describe finite structure up to isomorphism as model of two sentences.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, quantifiers

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $A$ be a finite structure.

> Find $σ_1\in$ Th$(A)$ such that any model of $σ_1$ has universe of the same
> cardinality as $A$.

> Now assume $L$ (the language we're using) has finitely many symbols.  Find a single existential sentence $σ_2$ (where an existential sentence is one of the form $\exists x_1 ... \exists x_n\varphi  $ where $\varphi$ is quantifier free) such that any model of $\lbrace σ_1, σ_2\rbrace$ is isomorphic to $A$.

The first part seems simple - if we assume $ |A|=n$, then we can just take a formula

$$ σ_1 = \exists x_1 ... \exists x_n(x_1\neq x_2 \wedge x_1\neq x_3 \wedge ... \wedge x_{n-1}\neq x_n \wedge \forall y (y=x_1 \lor y=x_2 \lor ... \lor y=x_n ))$$

saying that there are at least $n$ elements and at most $n$ elements.

I have no idea what form $σ_2$ would take - I tried thinking about a simple case where $ |A|=1$ and the language contains only a unary relation symbol $R$, but even then I don't know what you could do. Clearly in this case either $R^A = \emptyset$ or $R^A =A$, but then without knowing what interpretation $A$ gives to $R$ I don't see how you'd settle on the sentence. In this case it'd be easy enough to distinguish cases and just say e.g. that if $R^A =A$ then let $σ_2 = \exists x Rx$ but I struggle to see how you'd generalise to any arbitrary finite language and size of $A$.

I have no idea where to begin, so any help you could offer would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's start by observing that the idea (where our language consists of a single unary relation symbol $R$)

> if $R^A=A$ then let $\sigma_2=\exists xRx$.

does **not** work if there is more than one element in $A$: all this $\sigma_2$ says is that $R^A$ has at least one element. Already there are two (up to isomorphism) structures with two elements which satisfy $\sigma_2$ but are not isomorphic (one in which $R$ holds once, and one in which $R$ holds twice).

"$\forall xRx$" would do the job but of course we don't want that. So how can we do things with just existential quantifiers?

Well, let's think about a structure with two elements $u,v$ where $R$ holds of $u$ but not $v$. We can describe this as follows:

- There are two elements.
- There is one element where $R$ holds.
- There is one element where $R$ fails.

The first point is taken care of by $\sigma_1$. The second and third can be written together as $$(\exists xRx)\wedge (\exists x\neg Rx),$$ which in turn can be put in the form desired as

> $\exists x,y(Rx\wedge \neg Ry)$.

This last form suggests what we should be doing in general: to describe an $n$-element structure, we first fix some enumeration $a_1,...,a_n$ of its elements and then

> consider a sentence of the form $$\exists x_1,...,x_n([\mathsf{stuff}])$$ where "$\mathsf{stuff}$" describes how the $a_i$s interact - with $x_i$ interpreted as $a_i$.

This does **not** work, however: consider, in the language with a single unary relation $R$, a structure with three elements where $R$ holds on exactly one element versus a structure with three elements where $R$ holds on exactly two elements. If we look at the corresponding sentences of the type above, we get **equivalent** sentences (which we definitely don't want) since

> nothing is keeping the variables distinct.

We can fix this by

> folding appropriate distinctness clauses into the idea above, so that e.g. in the $R$-structure with two elements where $R$ holds once we'd get $$\exists x,y(x\not=y\wedge Rx\wedge\neg Ry).$$

At this point there are a couple questions to ask yourself:

- Where did we use the assumption of a finite language?
- Why do we need $\sigma_1$ as well as this $\sigma_2$?

Comment: This was super helpful, and I see what I was missing. Thank you!